# How to cancel Firebase Auth persist on logout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app has basic authentication form for registered admin user. In the SignIn form Email and pass are required and optionally 'Remember me' could be checked. Initially I set Auth persist to 'session' or 'local' depending on user choice, like showed in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)   // or .LOCAL
  .then(function() { 
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) ...
```

I have logout button calling `firebase.auth().signOut()`. It seems to logout the user, and redirects to login screen, but if page is reloaded, user is again logged in, without going through the SignIn form.
I thought about adding `setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)` to the logout logic, but (at least in the docs) it needs user credentials to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. Problem is at this point if the account is previously persisted, and loged in, user didn't leave `email` and `password`. Well, at least the password.
Is my approach fundamentally wrong, or do I need to clear local storage in some other way? Or maybe set persistUser to 'none' without calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword` again?

Answer (score 2):

set the persistence depending on the "Remember me checkbox"

```
// Checked
await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)

// Unchecked
await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

afterwards you can log in user with credentials without worrying about storing anything in the browser Local/Session storage and whenever you call

```
await firebase.auth().signOut()
```

user will be logged out